# Prevent markdown processor converting ">" to "&gt;" within <script> tags?

Tags: javascript, markdown

After processing with [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked),

```
<script>
for(e=0;a>e;++e)d[e]=b+b*Math.random();
</script>
```

becomes

```
<script>
for(e=0;a&gt;e;++e)d[e]=b+b*Math.random();
<script>
```

I thought marked was supposed to not change html within tags. Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: if it's an option, [showdown](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown) behaves as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm currently doing the markdown processing at the build step, so I'll have to look into using showdown server side.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling sanitize should do the trick (this does however mean that if you have html you want shown as text in you markdown outside code tags it might cause problems.)

```
var marked = require('marked');
marked.setOptions({
  sanitize: false
});

console.log(marked(
'<script>' +
'for(e=0;a>e;++e)d[e]=b+b*Math.random();' +
'</script>'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think hours that sanitize is false by default. That was the weirdness, other characters weren't escaped, just the >.